# Generating windows IoT 10 Image: ImageApp!ConfigureServicingStackLogging: Failed initializing WdsCore.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-iot-core-10, imx6

I'm finding several with the windows IoT 10 image generation for IMX6Q board when building .sln project (using visual studio 2017), specifically from the FFU generator.
The log file contains these following statements:

```
Run Feature Merger
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\tools\sign.cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\tools\bin\i386\sign.cmd
Begin Image generation
building image
imggen.cmd "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\\solution\iMXPlatform\Build\FFU\HummingBoard\HummingBoardTestOEMInput.xml.Release.ffu" "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\\board\HummingBoard\HummingBoardTestOEMInput.xml" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\MSPackages"
Microsoft (C) imageapp 10.0.10011.16384

ImageApp!ConfigureServicingStackLogging: Failed initializing WdsCore.dll.
EXEC : ThreadId8028 error : Please run imageapp.exe in an elevated console.

Exception non gérée : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable.

 à Microsoft.WindowsPhone.ImageUpdate.Tools.Common.LongPathFile.GetFileHandle(String normalizedPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
 à Microsoft.WindowsPhone.ImageUpdate.Tools.Common.LongPathFile.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
 à Microsoft.WindowsPhone.ImageUpdate.Tools.Common.LongPathFile.AppendAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
 à Microsoft.WindowsPhone.ImageUpdate.ImageApp.AppendToLog(String prepend, LoggingFunc LoggingFunc, String format, Object[] list)
 à Microsoft.WindowsPhone.ImageUpdate.ImageApp.LogErrorToFileAndConsole(String format, Object[] list)
 à Microsoft.WindowsPhone.ImageUpdate.Tools.Common.IULogger.Log(LoggingLevel level, String format, Object[] list)
 à Microsoft.WindowsPhone.ImageUpdate.ImageApp.Main()
"ImageApp "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\\solution\iMXPlatform\Build\FFU\HummingBoard\HummingBoardTestOEMInput.xml.Release.ffu" "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\\board\HummingBoard\HummingBoardTestOEMInput.xml" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\MSPackages" +StrictSettingPolicies" failed with error -532462766
!!!!! If the error was a Feature Manifest XML error, please check 
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\solution\iMXPlatform\GenerateTestFFU\fmlog.txt !!!!!
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(49,5): error MSB3073: La commande "
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(49,5): error MSB3073:       set Configuration=iMX6-Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(49,5): error MSB3073:       set Platform=ARM
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(49,5): error MSB3073:       set PkgOutput=C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\solution\iMXPlatform\Build\iMX6-Release\ARM\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(49,5): error MSB3073:       set OutDir=C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\imx6\windows\project-kayla-develop\build\solution\iMXPlatform\Build\iMX6-Release\ARM\GenerateTestFFU\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(49,5): error MSB3073:       call GenerateiMX6FFU.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(49,5): error MSB3073:     " s'est arrêtée avec le code 1.`
```

Comment: Have you run the IoTCoreShell.cmd as Administrator? [Here](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/issues/234) is a similar issue. What are versions of your ADK, WDK and COREKIT?

Comment: 17134 for wdk and adk,  17134.1 for corekit. The IoTCOreShell.cmd isn't included into the project

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I consider you build image following this tutorial and related tools:[IoT Core manufacturing guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/iot-core-manufacturing-guide)
While, where do you get the source files(the .sln solution) and which tutorial do you follow?

Comment: Thanks Rita for suggestion, the company has the private version of windows 10 IoT for imx6 and imx7, I'm currently working on building the FFU image of the develop project (which is failing until now). I was following the readme file provided with the project I'm working on.

Comment: The issue is followed on GitHub: [Buildimage fails for Dragonboard 410c on 1803 #234](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/issues/234)